# SQL Server Database Project's Deploy & Publish Targets

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

There are two distinct targets, `Deploy` and `Publish`, in SSDT project alongside `Build` but I can't find anything on what's the difference between them and which one should be used when? From what I can gather `.dbproj` used to use `Deploy` but `.sqlproj` supposedly replaced it with `Publish`, how come it's still there and what is it still used for?

`$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets`

```xml
<UsingTask TaskName="SqlBuildTask" AssemblyFile="$(SqlServerRedistPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.12.dll" />
<UsingTask TaskName="SqlDeployTask" AssemblyFile="$(SqlServerRedistPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.12.dll" />
<UsingTask TaskName="SqlPublishTask" AssemblyFile="$(SqlServerRedistPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.12.dll" />

<DeployDependsOn>
    BeforeDeploy;
    PreDeployEvent;
    SqlDeploy;
    PostDeployEvent;
    AfterDeploy
</DeployDependsOn>

<Target Name="Deploy" DependsOnTargets="$(DeployDependsOn)">

<PublishDependsOn>
    BeforePublish;
    PrePublishEvent;
    SqlPublish;
    PostPublishEvent;
    AfterPublish
</PublishDependsOn>

<Target Name="Publish" DependsOnTargets="$(PublishDependsOn)">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that Publish is used when you have a publish profile file describing the connection information, whereas Deploy is used when you do not have this file / do not wish to use one. Both are used by SSDT, the Deploy task is not just there for backward compatibility.

The Publish task takes in a "PublishProfile" property that specifies a saved publish profile xml file. The required server name, database name and other properties needed are read from that file. See [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4cd87c1d-a4e1-493d-80dd-10add488439b/using-build-framework-to-build-and-publish-ssdt-project-in-c?forum=ssdt) for some more information.

The deploy task is used when you do not have a publish profile (for example, the F5 debug deployment uses this, if I recall correctly). I believe this requires that the server, database name and other properties be set explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Do I understand it correctly that Deploy/Publish does not produce a delta script, and I might need create a custom "Script" task via DacServices and apply it with something like SMO?

Comment: Actually the tasks do create a delta script by default when running a deployment. I believe that to just generate the script without running deployment, set the "/p:UpdateDatabase=false" and specify the delta script name using "/p:ScriptName=MyScriptName.sql". For confirmation of these names check out the properties in the Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets file.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming it's for backwards compatibility.  Upgrading a SQL2008 dbproj to SQL2012 sqlproj after installing the SSDT update, you'd probably still want your dbprojects to function correctly until they are converted.